# Disable themes.php except for network admin username

Tags: users, security

How to remove and disable the admin menu item:

**Appearance > Themes** *for regular admin*.

Only allowing **Appearance > Themes**:

If you are logged in as multisite admin.

The regular admin can not change from one theme to another theme. Only the multisite admin can change themes.

Comment: the question may make more sense if you didn't call them network admins but rather "super admin" as network admin could mean different things to different people, super admin has a specific meaning though. Note that simply removing the capability to change/add/install themes from the administrator role should be enough for that menu to hide itself while still being visible for super admins, WordPress would do it automatically